# Why postgresql ignore the invalid casting

Tags: postgresql

I have a pg script as follow:

```
create table A (config jsonb);
insert into A values ('{"col1":"", "col2":""}');

create table B (col1 uuid, col2 varchar);
insert into B values ('64c7f2aa-f396-11eb-9a03-0242ac130003', 'aaaa');

UPDATE A SET config = config || 
                (
                    '{"col2":"' || 
                        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE col1 = (config->>'col1')::uuid) 
                            THEN (SELECT col2 FROM B WHERE col1 = (config->>'col1')::uuid) 
                            ELSE '' 
                        END || 
                    '"}'
                )::jsonb;
```

I know that in line 10 `WHERE col1 = (config->>'col1')::uuid` will cause error `invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""` when col1 is empty string,

in simular case `SELECT * FROM B WHERE col1 = ''::uuid` will cause the same error,

But why will the code pass without error if I remove line 5 `insert into B values ('64c7f2aa-f396-11eb-9a03-0242ac130003', 'aaaa');` and col1 in table A still empty string?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you sure you're not getting the following error when trying to insert an empty string into a `uuid` column? `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""`

Comment: Hi, @JimJones, I'm sorry for the mistake, line 5 in script is fixed, and I'm sure its insert into the table, but this error still exist on `UPDATE ...`

Comment: Are you sure the insert has the empty string ('') and not Null? True that  `insert into B values ('', 'aaaa');` is invalid and generates an error. But `insert into B values (null, 'aaaa');` is perfectly valid.  If you want an error when it is Null the you need to declare it as `col1 uuid not null`.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, thanks for your comment :). My main problem is happened on line 10 `SELECT * FROM B WHERE col1 = (config->>'col1')::uuid`, where I am not sure why pg show error in some case (line 5 is excuted successfully), but some cases will not (line 5 is removed).